# Python loop using regular words (elements that aren't objects)

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to loop a python list of regular words through the pandas "read_excel", and ideally the elements of the loop wouldn't be defined as any type of python object. Reason being, I need them to be string in one area, and in another area have them be available to be a dataframe name...

...seems I'm facing a trade-off between making them string or not: having them string in the loop doesn't allow them to be the dataframe name (option 1 below), whereas having them not a string (what I'm calling a 'regular word') allows them to be a dataframe name, but crashes the "read_excel" function (option 2 below). More background - I'm trying to turn 3 excel files into pandas dataframes (the excel files are called loopdata1.xlsx, loopdata2.xlsx, loopdata3.xlsx). Thanks for taking a look!

#### Option 1

```
list1 = ['loopdata1', 'loopdata2', 'loopdata3']
for x in list1:
    x = pd.read_excel(x + '.xlsx')
```

#### Option 2

```
list2 = [loopdata1, loopdata2, loopdata3]
for x in list2:
    y = str(x)
    x = pd.read_excel(y + '.xlsx')  

loopdata1.head()
```

Comment: you're mixing up the concepts of strings and variable names.

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: " ideally the elements of the loop wouldn't be defined as any type of python object" => sorry but this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

While it makes some sense, when exploring a language, to try to think in terms of the concepts you *want* to have exist and see what works, at some point (and if you want the people who might be able to help to understand you, that point needs to come before posing questions) you need to take a step back and understand the concepts actually used by the language.

What you're calling a "regular word' isn't a thing.  When you say

```
list2 = [loopdata1, loopdata2, loopdata3]
```

this is *not* a list of the words `loopdata1`, `loopdata2`, and `loopdata3`.  It is a list whose first element has whatever value happened to be assigned to the variable named `loopdata1`; and whose 2nd element has whatever value happened to be assigned to the variable named `loopdata2`; etc.

The list does not, in fact, retain any knowledge that its first value came from a variable named `loopdata1`; it just holds its copy of the value.  (When your variables are object references or similar, it can sometimes look as though what I just said weren't true; but it is.  What happens is, both the original variable and the list element have copies of the same reference, which reference the same underlying object.  So changes made through one reference can be seen through the other, as though the variables were linked somehow; but really they are just independent copies of the same reference.)

Without seeing more of your code, I can't know what values you're actually assigning in your "option 2".  Could be the `None` value, or some other value you'd initialized the variables (`loopdata1`, `loopdata2`, and `loopdata3`) to.

Now you say you want to use the values as the "dataframe names"; which from your code I take to mean that you want to assign the dataframe created from `loopdata1.xls` to a variable named `loopdata1`.  If you want this to be driven by the data in the list, you can't do exactly that (at least, not in any reasonable way); but you can do something very close

```
dataframes = {}
list1 = ['loopdata1', 'loopdata2', 'loopdata3']
for x in list1:
    dataframes[x] = pd.read_excel(x + '.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, you're closer than I was. I'm trying to import loopdata1.xlsx, and my understanding is that pd.read_excel() turns it into a dataframe. I'm setting it equal to x in that line to try naming the dataframe as loopdata1 without the .xlsx tacked onto the end. Your code for me doesn't crash, but it doesn't make a dataframe called loopdata1 -- instead I get this error code: name 'loopdata1' is not defined